# FFMPEG change Tone Frequency, keep length (Pitch Audio)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, pitch

How can I change the *Tone frequency*.
This Example only pitches it by *keeping the old* tone frequency and only decrease the length of File.

For Example, I have a constant 100 Herz tone (as mp3) and I want it *to change* 90 Herz

```
 ffmpeg -i 100h.mp3 -af atempo=100/90 90h.mp3
```

This Example doesn't work for me, it sounds the same

[inputfile Mp3](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13396469/test.mp3.html)
[outputfile Mp3](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13396468/output.mp3.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

finally, by combining the `asetrate` and `resample` from Gyan, with `atempo`, the following works and preserves also the audio length

for example: use **0.9** for **90%** of the frequenz

```
 ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -af asetrate=44100*0.9,aresample=44100,atempo=1/0.9 output.mp3
```

Answer (score 9):

Basic method is

```
ffmpeg -i 100h.mp3 -af asetrate=44100*0.9,aresample=44100 90h.mp3
```

where `44100` should be replaced with the input sample rate.