# How to adjust the Pitch of a Video using FFmpeg

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, pitch

I am new to FFmpeg and want to adjust the pitch of a video. I don't know how to do it. I have checked the manual too but nothing worked. I want to change the pitch of the audio which is in the Video. Is there any way to change the pitch without extracting and merging audio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPEG change Tone Frequency (Pitch Audio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374590/ffmpeg-change-tone-frequency-pitch-audio)

Comment: *"Is there any way to change the pitch without extracting and merging audio?"* `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -af "asetrate=44100*0.9,aresample=44100" output.mp4`